# undefined method `after_commit' for Candidate:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am beginner in mongodb. I am working on rails 4. I am trying to upload files using "mongoid-paperclip", but when I try to upload the files I am getting the above error. The error is in the line:

"has_mongoid_attached_file :logo"

app/models/image.rb:6:in `<class:Image>'
   app/models/image.rb:1:in`',
   app/controllers/candidates_controller.rb:50:in `profile'

Please help me to solve this error at the earliest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was recently fixed on the master branch of this gem:

https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip/issues/46

Try using the version from github.

Comment: Oxtub: :Thank you so much. I debugged this error and now I am able to upload image files.But, When I try to upload pdf/text_files/videos, I am getting "undefined method `before_pdf_post_process' for Image:Class", . Please guide me, how to include ":processor" code into my code.